# is there a simpler alternative to `calc` when handling margins in a line-break?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When creating a responsive layout with elements that have a margin between them, their alignment gets messed up when the viewport causes a line-break. I posted a possible workaround using `calc()`, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution. See my example code-snippet below for further context.

I am already aware of the negative-margin-on-parent solution. This doesn't work in a majority of my cases. Looking for any other alternatives.

```css
h4{
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px 10px 0;
}
div{
  background:lightgray;
  width:600px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2),
div:nth-of-type(3){
  width: 250px;
}

button{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding:10px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3)>button{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>DESKTOP</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>MOBILE</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>"CALC" WORKAROUND</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's arguable whether this is simpler, but it can be done without calc. The problem is that buttons of auto width are stuck with shrink-to-fit characteristics. That's not what you want. So we need to surround the buttons in containers with more block container-like auto width behaviour, then the button widths can be 100% of those. Like this:

```css
h4{
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px 10px 0;
}
div{
  background:lightgray;
  width:600px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2),
div:nth-of-type(3),
div:nth-of-type(4){
  width: 250px;
}

button{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding:10px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3)>button{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

div:nth-of-type(4)>span{
  display:block;
  margin:0 10px;
}
div:nth-of-type(4)>span>button{
  width: 100%;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>DESKTOP</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>MOBILE</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>"CALC" WORKAROUND</h4>
  <button>BUTTON 1</button><button>BUTTON 2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>"Block Container" WORKAROUND</h4>
  <span><button>BUTTON 1</button></span><span><button>BUTTON 2</button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you this isn't necessarily "simpler", but I'm interested in alternate approaches like this - thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning in an answer like this - all the nth-of-type selectors, etc. could (should) likely be replaced with useful, re-usable _classes_ that help address the relevant elements.